# How can I add the books I wrote to my CV?

Tags: resume

I have written two books about software development and I must admit they have a very fine rating on amazon.

However, I have no idea how I can add them to my current CV to highlight my familiarity and expertise in software development.

Should I add the cover picture and maybe the cover text or would that be too much?

Comment: If you wrote them then just place them under "major acomplishments" make sure they are actually good though.  The title and ISBN number is enough in a situation like this.

Comment: Vote to Close? How is not a real question?

Comment: @JimG. The question itself is on topic and likely to be relevant to other users. I would also like to personally add that experience in software development in no way translates into being a master of CV's, Resumes, Interviews or anything else pertaining to using skills developed outside their area of expertise.

Comment: @RhysW: It is indeed on topic; but it's not a real challenge that the OP faces. Remember, we're "optimizing for pearls, not sand." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Comment: @JimG. Please join me in the chat room

Comment: @JimG. - Those questions belong on meta not here in comments.

Comment: @Chad: I agree. This discussion got a little long-winded.

Comment: Staple them together?

Answer (score 5):

A Cover Picture and the cover text would definitely be too much. You're trying to list your relevant skills not make a sale to them.

In CV's that are specific and rigid, e.g some companies give you a blank template that you must fill in then placing this in the section called 'Other', this would probably be the best place to list them in this kind of format:

```
Written book on 'Genetic Engineering' called "How to breed wrestling plants", published 2004 - ISBN 1337
```

This then shows what its about, what its called and when it was written.

If you received any awards for your books then listing those underneath would be a good idea too to highlight how well received your books were.

--

If you have the freedom to write your CV as you choose then an alternate option is to highlight that you have this experience by having a specific section titled 'Publications' where this relevant information can be listed as above.

This would also aid you in drawing more attention to this experience than putting it in other.

Comment: I would also suggest adding the ISBN number.

Answer (score 4):

A CV is about selling yourself, so you need to weigh the importance of the books to the roles you are applying for, against other experience or qualifications that you have. If the books are important they should be nearer the top of your CV and if they're particularly relevant, mentioned in your covering letter. You could, for example, list the books as part of your work experience near the front of your CV, if they're important, or, otherwise in a separate publications section at the end. If you took time out of work to write them, then there is a stronger argument for listing them in your experience section, so what you did in the "gap" is obvious.

Finally, if the books have got good recommendations on amazon, say so! Likewise, it would be certainly be worth quoting positive, official reviews.

> "Cottage Gardening", published 20xx, rated 4.5 on amazon.com out of 234 reviews. Reviewed in Gardeners' World, xx July 20xx: "Root and branch coverage of your cottage garden".

Comment: I don't really feel that reviews on amazon are an accurate or unbiased representation on the book compared to say, licensed publishers and reputable reviewers

Comment: @RhysW You've got a point there, certainly if you consider some of the recent scandals re reviews of fiction and academic books that have [occurred here in the UK](http://www.guardian.co.uk/books/2010/jul/16/orlando-figes-fake-amazon-reviews) recently! Nevertheless, in my field, of software engineering, I use amazon reviews as my first source of information as to whether to buy a book. And if there are enough reviews, say 20 or 30 or more, I find the average rating to be a good indicator. But if the OP has positive comments from official reviews, absolutely worth mentioning those too.